# Moving fields from QA to Dev Org with same Api Name

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, change-set, developer, admin

I have some fields in an org that I am working in building out some functionality. I was told that I need to move them into my dev org so that we can refresh the other org. I had originally build some functionality in my dev org but rebuilt it in QA manually. I realize now this was a bad idea, but the fields exist in both orgs with the same API names. I've tried googling to figure out what sort of issues this is going to cause but cannot seem to find an answer. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If they're the same data type, nothing happens when you deploy fields with duplicate API names. If they are of differing types, you may get errors. In that case, just rename the fields so they have a new API name before trying to deploy again. Be aware that changing between some data types, like Phone to Number, may delete all data for all records in that field. Since this is apparently not a live org, that's probably an acceptable consequence.